# convert report data to csv format and send attachment in mail using apex

Tags: apex

Please find below code,I am getting attachment in html format.
But i need attachment in csv format.
Let me know what changes I have to do ?

```
global class MonthlyScheduler implements System.Schedulable,Database.AllowsCallouts 
    {
        global String ReportId;
        global MonthlyScheduler(String ReportId){
            this.ReportId = ReportId;
        }
        global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

            sendNow(this.ReportId);

        }
    @future(callout=true)
    global static void sendNow(String ReportId){

        ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/'+ReportId+'?csv=1');
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();        
       attachment.setFileName('report.csv');
       attachment.setBody(report.getContent());
       attachment.setContentType('text/csv');
       Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } );

        message.setSubject('Report');

        message.setPlainTextBody('The report is attached.');

        message.setToAddresses( new String[] { 'XXXXX@gmail.com' } );

        Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message } );
    }
}
```

Comment: I pasted the code starting with `ApexPages.PageReference` in anon apex and it worked fine. Try it w/o the @future.

Comment: without @future it is giving error

Comment: @cropredy, You got attachment in csv format?

Comment: Yes I did.  And it was openable in excel

Comment: please attach output and code

Comment: please can you send @cropredy

Comment: this is weird, in one org I get a perfect csv; in a different org I get the html as you observed.

Comment: It is working in classic

Comment: You can try doing this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284150/i-am-not-get-the-tabular-report-body-in-the-attached-email/284174?noredirect=1#comment426885_284174

Comment: Thank u ,its working

Comment: I have to schedule above code in UI,  I tried scheduling but getting below error  
  First error: core.apexpages.exceptions.ApexPagesGenericException: 404 status code return from request to https://cs83.salesforce.com/null?csv=1&isdtp=p1&inline=1..please help to schedule this class using schedule jobs on ui

Answer (score 1):

i did it this way and it works just fine

```
String instanceName = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
string url=instanceName+'/servlet/PrintableViewDownloadServlet?isdtp=p1&reportId='+reportId;
ApexPages.PageReference objPage = new ApexPages.PageReference(url);
```

the only limitation is that i couldn't add filters dynamicaly

Answer (score 0):

You need `ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/'+ReportId+'?csv=1&isdtp=p1');`

Instead of `ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/'+ReportId+'?csv=1');`

I don't know the exact details, but the extra code helps parse the report correctly.