# How to call report in xlsx file format

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, singleemailmessage, custom-reports, xlsx

could you please help me how to call report Xlsx file format, i am tried to below code, but i am not get the result:

```
public class BatchUtilClass {
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void futureMethod() {
        list <Report> reportList = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Report WHERE Name = 'users logins' limit 1];
        system.debug('list'+reportList);
        String reportId = (String)reportList.get(0).get('Id');
        system.debug('reportids'+reportId);
        ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/00O3N000000097hg9v?csv=1&isdtp=p1');
        // ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/00O3N000000097hg9v?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=xls');
        system.debug('pagereport'+report);
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        system.debug('atachment'+attachment);
        attachment.setFileName('Report.csv');
        // attachment.setFileName('Report.xlsx');
        attachment.setBody(report.getContent());
        attachment.setContentType('text/csv');
        // attachment.setContentType('text/xlsx');
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } );
        message.setSubject('users logins Report');
        message.setPlainTextBody('The testing report is attached.');
        message.setToAddresses( new String[] { 'hkvts2@gmail.com' } );
        Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message } );

    }
}
```

Comment: (a) No need to beg in comments--we're here to help you, and (b) "not get the result" doesn't tell us how to help you. What problems are you having?

Comment: when i am trying to scheduling this above class ,i am not get the report file in xlsx .xlsx format code is comments in code

Comment: this can help you https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284150/i-am-not-get-the-tabular-report-body-in-the-attached-email/284174?noredirect=1#comment426885_284174

Comment: @KushalChauhan Can you clarify how that applies? That question is CSV format.

Comment: I am using xlsx format:: ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/00O3N000000JYObUAO?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=xlsx');

Comment: you can create excel in 'xls' format by changing csv=1 to excel=1 in the answer that i provided and changing setContentType('text/vnd.openxmlformats'); i dont think we can get 'xlsx' though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not asking for XLSX format. You're asking for either CSV or XLS format, depending on which lines are commented out. Changing the filename or MIME type on the attachment object has no effect on what file format is produced.

Inspecting the URL generated when exporting an XLSX-format report in Lightning yields the URL format

```
https://<mydomain>.my.salesforce.com/servlet/PrintableViewDownloadServlet?isdtp=p1&reportId=<report id>
```

Presumably, you'd need to ask for that URL to obtain the desired format.

Comment: my URL:https://XXX--preprod.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Report/00O3N000000097hg9v/view?queryScope=userFolders

Comment: you are saying this this format:https://XXX--preprod.lightning.force.com/lightning/r?isdtp=p1&reportId='00O3N000000097hg9v'

Comment: @HKV No, I'm saying that when you export an XLSX file in Lighting Report viewer, the URL format is as shown above. I haven't attempted to download that in Visualforce myself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files), the correct way to set the Content Type for an xlsx file is to use `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`, not `text/xlsx`.

Comment: I am tryied this one but once download file, file format is not matched.